# Pivot_ui showing only rows and cold input fields

Tags: javascript, python, pivot, pivot-table

I am having issues with pivot_ui in python.

Pivot_ui(df) is only showing rows and column input fields. I can't find the value field in user interface.

Any help is much appreciated.